# PHP mail with SQL row details

Tags: php, phpmailer

i just creating contact form, for log in users. So i have to get their name, and e-mail... after few hour of trying i using Class selector... but before that i had error like:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

My code(trying to convert for a string):

```
     class MyClass
    {
        public $name;

        public function __construct($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

        public function __toString()
        {
            try 
            {
                return (string) $this->name;
            } 
            catch (Exception $exception) 
            {
                return '';
            }
        }
        }
    }
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck > 0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $name = new MyClass('"'. $row['user_first'] . '"');
    $userumail = new MyClass('"'. $row['user_email'] . '"');
```

So after that i have:

> syntax error,unexpected ' public'

part of my html mail(because mail is to long i put only 1 line):

```
<h3 style='text-align:center'>Message from: $name e-mail: $userumail></h3></br>
```

Please give me a advice xD

Comment: why create a class inside a loop?

Comment: _"poublic"_? Sounds like you've got a typo somewhere. Also, defining a class in a loop isn't going to work as PHP classes cannot be redefined

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer, so if somebody will have similar issue with MAIL function.
simply use mysqli like:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck>0){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['user_first'] );
      $userumail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['user_email']);
```

After that you will be able to use your rows data as string:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 style='text-align:center'>Message from: $name mail: $userumail</h3></br>
</body>
</html>
";
```

So Mail will send user name and email from database. :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the errors but not sure if it will help you though...

1) Your public function __construct($name) has no closing brace }.

2) You don't need to convert  $row['user_first']  to string. Its already in string format as long as you store it as a string in your database.

P.s I don't understand your code that well , think I'll be able to help you better if you rewrite the question.